# url rewrite with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I will inform you briefly what I am doing and where I will need your help.

I am building blog hosting site. I finished CMS and now i am doing user pages.

My idea was to create .htaccess rules so every user and blog owner will have its own blog URL, like: `XXX.bloghost.com`, where `XXX` is blog name or blog owner name.

Just to mention that I will use 2 more parameters in URL so here are examples of URLs:

```
XXX.bloghost.com -> www.bloghost.com/index.php?user=XXX

XXX.bloghost.com/NEWS -> www.bloghost.com/index.php?user=XXX&category=NEWS

XXX.bloghost.com/NEWS/SAMPLE -> www.bloghost.com/index.php?user=XXX&category=NEWS&post=SAMPLE
```

Here is my current .htaccess file (UPDATED):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.bloghost.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).bloghost.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.+)/(.+)/(.+) blog.php?blog_id=$1&category=$2&post=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.+)/(.+) blog.php?blog_id=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.+) blog.php?blog_id=$1 [L,QSA]


ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

I would really need some help with this. I tried and followed several tutorials on this but with no luck.

Also, can this .htaccess block or redirect all mistyped or not existing URLs to some page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you must configure you subdomains for the wildcard

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com
```

And be sure that DNS configured for wildcards too. Than use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [QSA]
```

So after this page `http://some.domain.com/news` will go to `http://www.domain.com/some/news`
And than process the url as usual (just for example):

```
RewriteRule (.+)/(.+)/(.+) index.php?user=$1&category=$2&post=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.+)/(.+) index.php?user=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
// and so on
```

But I think that second part should be handled with php routing system.

Comment: Thank you Atma, I will try this later and post results here ... cheers m8

Comment: I just tried your sugestion, but with no luck

URl www.bloghost.com/XXX/NEWS works like a charm, but URL like XXX.bloghost.com give me "server not found" error. This is my .htaccess file:

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.otvorko.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).otvorko.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.+)/(.+)/(.+) blog.php?blog_id=$1&category=$2&post=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.+)/(.+) blog.php?blog_id=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.+) blog.php?blog_id=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Do you have properly configured DNS & web server (Apache) for the wildcard? `ServerAlias www.otvorko.net dotvorko.net *.otvorko.net` for apache and something like `*.otvorko.net A 111.222.33.44` in the domain dns record?

Comment: not sure is it properly configured ... i added 

*.otvorko.net A ttl(300) IP  in control panel of my hosting provider.

maybe to wait for DNS update?

Answer (score 0):

@atma already handled the real redirection.  Just a quick add-on for error handling in .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Easy!  Any 404 error will be directed to bloghost.com/error.php.  Substitute your path and page/script to display for errors.